# Contacts I created wont come up on search

Tags: drupal, contacts, search

I have installed Drupal and CiviCRM. I have created a new Drupal role and given the following permission

- CiviCRM: add contacts
- CiviCRM: view my contact
- CiviCRM: edit my contact
- CiviCRM: access CiviCRM (This permission gave me access to use search
  and advanced search)

I can create contacts. But when I search I don't see the contacts I created. 
My requirement is, I should be able to see the contacts that I created(not other contacts) when I search.

Is this possible  ?

Comment: One question I have is "How many people have the requirement of seeing their own contacts but no others?"  If it's just you, or a few folks (fewer than 10?) then @lcdservices' answer of "use ACLs" makes sense.  Past that, I think you'll want a custom extension because it will get very tedious otherwise!

Comment: Basically everyone who is a user needs to see only their contacts

Comment: I have found a solution and posted it here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/20638/5039

Answer (score 2):

"View my contact" grants the ability to see your own contact record, not other contacts you have created. So as currently constructed, you're able to create new contacts but not view them. You have two options -- grant the View all contacts permission (which would allow the user to see all contacts, not only those they have created), or explore using the advanced ACL features to determine what records can be viewed by the contact (see: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#native-civicrm-acls). That may require some additional work to segment contacts into groups based on who created them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to do this in Drupal by adding the [Permissioned Relationship](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.relatedpermissions) extension, and then use a webform so that when you add a Contact, it creates a relationship between you (as Contact 1) and the folk you are adding. Then when you go in to civicrm you will see all those folk that you have a Permissioned Relationship too.

Comment: So I have actually been told to use the civicrm UI itself so right now staying away from webforms. Cant I do the same without using web forms? I mean add a relationship when I add a contact through the civicrm interface

Comment: @nmeegama You could do that with a custom extension, yes, or possibly using CiviRules (or Drupal Rules with civicrm_entity).  Then the Permissioned Relationship extension will do the permissioning.